# expand table row based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown with values. For instance, when I click level 1 in the dropdown, I'd like to expand the first row of the table, when level 2 is clicked I want to expand till second level in the table(dish items). When all is selected from the dropdown, I'd like to expand all the rows of the table.

```
              <select [(ngModel)]="expandModel"
                (ngModelChange)="getoptionedExpansion($event)">
                <option value="lvl1">level 1 </option>
                <option value="lvl2">level 2</option>
                <option value="lvl3"> Level 3 </option>
                <option value="lvl4">level 4 </option>
                <option value="all">All</option>
              </select>
```

Table :

```
    <table style="width:100%">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of users">
          <tr (click)="data.hideThis= !data.hideThis" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #DDE3ED;">
            <td class="mainTitleFont cursor-pointer" style="font-size:16px">
              <span *ngIf="data.hideThis">
                -
              </span>
              <span *ngIf="!data.hideThis">
                +
              </span>
              {{data.itemName}}</td>
          </tr>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data.subItemsList">
            <tr (click)="item.hideThis= !item.hideThis" style="font-size:15px; background-color: #edf2ef"
              [hidden]="!data.hideThis">
              <td *ngIf="data.hideThis">
                <span *ngIf="item.hideThis">
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; -
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="!item.hideThis">
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; +
                </span>
                {{item.subitemName}}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let prod of item.items">
              <tr (click)="prod.hideThis= !prod.hideThis" style="font-size:14px; background-color: #f2f2f2"
                [hidden]="!data.hideThis || !item.hideThis">
                <td>
                  <span *ngIf="prod.hideThis">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;-
                  </span>
                  <span *ngIf="!prod.hideThis">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; +
                  </span>
                  {{prod.itemName}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let stock of prod.stocksList">
                <tr (click)="stock.hideThis= !stock.hideThis" style="font-size:13px; background:#f5f7f6;"
                  [hidden]="!data.hideThis || !item.hideThis || !prod.hideThis">
                  <td>
                    <span *ngIf="stock.hideThis">
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;-
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="!stock.hideThis">
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; +
                    </span>
                    {{stock.stockName}}
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let prodItem of stock.itemItemsList">
                  <tr (click)="prodItem.hideThis= !prodItem.hideThis" style="font-size:12px"
                    [hidden]="!data.hideThis || !item.hideThis || !stock.hideThis || !prod.hideThis">
                    <td style="width:100%">
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; {{prodItem.itemName}} <br>
                      <div class="list-class">
                        <span>
                          <ul>
                            <li> Portion</li>
                            <li>{{prodItem.date}} </li>
                          </ul>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </ng-container>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here's the [DEMO!!!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-search-list-ncjhfa?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Answer (score 0):

you only need use forEach and give value to hideThis of each "children", e.g.

```
getoptionedExpansion(event)
{
  if (event=="lvl1")
    this.users.forEach(x=>x.hideThis=true)

  if (event=="lvl2")
  {
    this.users.forEach(x=>x.hideThis=true)
    this.users.forEach(x=>{
      x.subItemsList.forEach(y=>{
        y.hideThis=true
      })
    })
  }
  ...you need make some similar with the others options and elements...
}
```

But, sincerely, I choose the name of the variables in a way more comfortable, why not use for all children the same name of the property? it's a bit chaotic your choice of name of variables

Comment: how can I access hideThis from the component?

Comment: sorry the confusion. I want to say that "I would choose other name of variables". I used yours